# How can I make "screens of black for grey" in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pantone

I need to prepare our company logo for printing on some envelopes.  These are the instructions I was given:

> *Everything as two spot colors - Reflex Blue and 100% Black with screens of black for the greys*

I've already taken care of making sure my blue is the Reflex blue pantone in Illustrator, but what does it mean to use "100% black with screens of black for greys?"

Comment: I suppose they mean tints. You can make those by selecting a black shape, and then setting the tint in the `Color` palette.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a grey, use 50% black or 30% black or 20% black....

Don't use a "grey" color.

(You can also use 50% Reflex, 30% Reflex, 20% reflex, etc.)

Everything needs to be those two colors, set at *any* percentage.

[image]